# Execv failing even when command is available

Tags: c, fork, execv

I'm trying to call execv after manually saerching for the program to execute.

In my case,
c is a struct which has args as an array of strings having the arguments passed while receiving input. nargs is the number of arguments.
c->args[0] would contain "ls","cat" etc.

I tried printing the value of the args[0], fullPath etc. in my child process. They all show values like "/bin/ls","/bin/cat" etc. But when I call execv, it returns -1 with an errno of 2, which I understand is the error for "No such file or directory". But I'm sure the file is there because thats what my PathResolver is returning after checking all permissions.
Can anyone point where I might have made a mistake.

//The part happening inside child

```
  char *fullPath = PathResolver(c->args[0],1,&permission);
  printf("FullPath: %s -- Permission: %d\n",fullPath,permission);
  if(permission==0)
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: Command not found\n",c->args[0]);
  }
  else if(permission==-1)
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: Permission denied\n",c->args[0]);
  }
  else
  {
    char* args[c->nargs+1];
    int m=0;
    for(m=0;m<c->nargs;m++)
    {
          strcpy(args[m],c->args[m]);
    }
    args[c->nargs] = NULL;
    printf("%d\n",execv(args[0], args));
    printf("errno: %d\n",errno);
 }
```

PathResolver function

```
   char* PathResolver(char *command, int ResolverMode, int *Permission)
   {
 *Permission = 0;
 char *returnString;
 returnString = malloc((sizeof(char)));
 char *strPath = getenv("PATH");
 char *del = ":";
 char *strToken = strtok(strPath,del);
 FILE *f;
 while(strToken)
 {
    char filePath[100];
    sprintf(filePath,"%s/%s",strToken,command);
    if(access(filePath,F_OK)>=0)
    {
        if(access(filePath,X_OK)>=0)
        {
            *Permission = 1;
            sprintf(returnString,"%s%s ",returnString,filePath);
            if(ResolverMode == 1)
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            *Permission = -1;
        }
    }
    strToken = strtok(NULL,del);
  }
  sprintf(returnString,"%s\b",returnString);
  return returnString;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy(args[m],c->args[m]);` is undefined behaviour, because `args[m]` is not a pointer to valid memory.

The following might be simpler:

```
char * args[c->nargs + 1];

for (size_t m = 0; m != c->nargs; ++m)
{
     args[m] = c->args[m];
}

args[c->nargs] = NULL;
```

There's no need to copy the strings.

(This may not be your actual problem, but it certainly prevents your program from being correct.)

Comment: But I'm still able to print the values of args[m] and confirm that it is the right value. Maybe, I was lucky. I would implement it in any case. I also tried directly passing c->args[0], but that was not working either. That is why i thought I'll duplcate the string array and try. In any case, this is useful. I'll check it for sure

Answer (score 0):

`execv()` expects the program name to be prefixed by a **full** path as 1st parameter.

To have `PATH` searched instead of providing a path use `execvp()`.

---

**Update**:

Also this line

```
 returnString = malloc((sizeof(char)));
```

does only allocate `1` byte to `returnString`, which is way to few for how you use `returnString`.

Comment: For eg, it has to be something like '/bin/ls', right? That is what I'm getting from the PathResolver functiona and assigning it as the first argument. But it is not working.

Comment: @Torpedo: I cannot see where you are assigning to `args` anything else then value from `c->args`.